# T-SQL Query with multiple union statements providing error of unequal expressions

Tags: t-sql, join, union

With running the entire T-SQL code below it seems I am getting the following error below.

Troubleshoot Steps:

1. Run each block of code before each "UNION" (Each block executes fine and returns results")
2. Checked all syntax for each block and found no underlining syntax errors
3. Executed the last three blocks of codes for sections containing "PartTran" and three blocks execute correctly.
4. Executed the first two blocks of code and error is provided

I'm rather stumped on this error because if I take the first block of code and I one line in the select list and group by list for a specific column,all of the code runs. From what I can tell I have the same columns selected and grouped for each block of code but when running all blocks together I receive the error. Any help would be appreciated!

Execution Error:

Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

```
    SELECT 
             OH.OrderStatus
            ,OH.ShipByTime
            ,CS.PriceTolerance
            ,OH.OrderNum
            ,OH.ExtCompany
            ,CS.[Name]
            ,OH.TotalInvoiced - OH.TotalDiscount AS 'net_sales_order'
            ,OH.CustNum
            ,OH.ShipToNum
            ,OH.ShipToCustNum
            ,SUM(CAST(OD.OrderQty AS int)) AS QtySum
            ,COUNT(OD.OrderLine) AS LineCnt
    FROM erp.customer AS CS WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN erp.orderhed AS OH WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON CS.custnum = OH.custnum
    LEFT JOIN erp.OrderDtl as OD
        ON OH.OrderNum = OD.OrderNum
            AND OH.ExtCompany = OD.ExtCompany
    WHERE (OH.VoidOrder <> '1') AND OH.OrderStatus BETWEEN 'N' AND 'Q' --order status is currently empty in E10LiveDB on RASE10PROD
    GROUP BY 
         OH.OrderStatus
        ,OH.ShipByTime
        ,CS.PriceTolerance
        ,OH.OrderNum
        ,OH.ExtCompany
        ,CS.[Name]
        ,OH.TotalInvoiced - OH.TotalDiscount
        ,OH.CustNum
        ,OH.ShipToNum
        ,OH.ShipToCustNum

    UNION

    SELECT --PT.STATUS
        PT.TranDate
        ,'CONSIGN' AS Expr1
        ,PT.PartNum
        ,0 AS 'ext'
        ,'KRAFTMAID' + ' - ' + PT.LotNum AS Expr2
        ,SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), PT.Acttranqty * PT.MtlUnitCost)) AS Expr3
        ,PT.LotNum
        ,0 AS Expr4
        ,'KRAFTMAID' AS Expr5
        ,SUM(CAST(PT.Acttranqty AS int)) AS QtySum
        ,COUNT(PT.OrderLine) AS LineCnt
    FROM erp.PartTran AS PT WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN erp.PartWhse AS PW WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON PT.PartNum = PW.PartNum
    INNER JOIN erp.PartLot AS PL WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON PT.PartNum = PL.PartNum
            AND PL.FirstRefDate < GETDATE()
            AND PL.ExpirationDate > GETDATE()
    LEFT JOIN erp.Customer AS C WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON PT.CustNum = C.CustNum
            AND C.CustID = '43360'
    WHERE (
            PT.LotNum IN (
                'KM'
                ,'KMUT'
                )
            )
    --  AND (X.STATUS < 'S')
    --  AND XL.shipped = 0
    GROUP BY --X.STATUS,
        PT.TranDate
        ,PT.PartNum
        ,PT.LotNum

    UNION

    SELECT -- X.STATUS
         PT.TranDate
        ,'CONSIGN' AS Expr1
        ,PT.PartNum
        ,0 AS 'ext'
        ,'AMERICAN WOODMARK' + ' - ' + PT.LotNum AS Expr2
        ,SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), PT.Acttranqty * PT.MtlUnitCost)) AS Expr3
        ,PT.LotNum
        ,0 AS Expr4
        ,'AMERICAN WOODMARK' AS Expr5
        ,SUM(CAST( PT.Acttranqty AS int)) AS QtySum
        ,COUNT(PT.OrderLine) AS LineCnt
        FROM erp.PartTran AS PT WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN erp.PartWhse AS PW WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON PT.PartNum = PW.PartNum
    INNER JOIN erp.PartLot AS PL WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON PT.PartNum = PL.PartNum
            AND PL.FirstRefDate < GETDATE()
            AND PL.ExpirationDate > GETDATE()
    LEFT JOIN erp.Customer AS C WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON PT.CustNum = C.CustNum
            AND C.CustID = '43360'
    WHERE (PT.LotNum = 'AWNC')
    --  AND (X.STATUS < 'S')
    --  AND XL.shipped = 0
    GROUP BY --X.STATUS,
        PT.TranDate
        ,PT.PartNum
        ,PT.LotNum

    UNION

    SELECT -- X.STATUS
        PT.TranDate
        ,'CONSIGN' AS Expr1
        ,PT.PartNum
        ,0 AS 'ext'
        ,'AMERICAN WOODMARK' + ' - ' + PT.LotNum AS Expr2
        ,SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), PT.Acttranqty * PT.MtlUnitCost)) AS Expr3
        ,PT.LotNum
        ,0 AS Expr4
        ,'AMERICAN WOODMARK' AS Expr5
        ,SUM(CAST(PT.Acttranqty AS int)) AS QtySum
        ,COUNT(PT.OrderLine) AS LineCnt
        FROM erp.PartTran AS PT WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN erp.PartWhse AS PW WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON PT.PartNum = PW.PartNum
    INNER JOIN erp.PartLot AS PL WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON PT.PartNum = PL.PartNum
            AND PL.FirstRefDate < GETDATE()
            AND PL.ExpirationDate > GETDATE()
    LEFT JOIN erp.Customer AS C WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON PT.CustNum = C.CustNum
            AND C.CustID = '11088'
    WHERE (PT.LotNum = 'AWAZ')
    --  AND (X.STATUS < 'S')
    --AND XL.shipped = 0
    GROUP BY -- X.STATUS,
        PT.TranDate
        ,PT.PartNum
        ,PT.LotNum

    UNION

    SELECT -- X.STATUS
        PT.TranDate
        ,'CONSIGN'
        ,PT.PartNum
        ,0 AS 'ext'
        ,'STAR MARK' + ' - ' + PT.LotNum
        ,SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), PT.Acttranqty * PT.MtlUnitCost))
        ,PT.LotNum
        ,0
        ,'AMERICAN WOODMARK'
        ,SUM(CAST(PT.Acttranqty AS int)) AS QtySum
        ,COUNT(PT.OrderLine) AS LineCnt
            FROM erp.PartTran AS PT WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN erp.PartWhse AS PW WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON PT.PartNum = PW.PartNum
    INNER JOIN erp.PartLot AS PL WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON PT.PartNum = PL.PartNum
            AND PL.FirstRefDate < GETDATE()
            AND PL.ExpirationDate > GETDATE()
    LEFT JOIN erp.Customer AS C WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON PT.CustNum = C.CustNum
            AND C.CustID IN
             (
                '49023'
                ,'11444'
                            )   
    WHERE PT.LotNum = 'SM'
    --  AND X.STATUS < 'S'
    --  AND XL.shipped = 0
    GROUP BY --X.STATUS,
        PT.TranDate
        ,PT.PartNum
        ,PT.LotNum
    GO
```

Comment: Did you forget to comment out  `OH.OrderStatus ` in the first block?

Comment: No I left that there, I can't find a respected column for STATUS in the underlying blocks but the first block of code I found OrderStatus. Though the first block of code does not have the same amount of columns being referenced as the other blocks. Would "orderstatus" have that affect of it not being equal? It has been awhile since i have delved in unions so please forgive me.

Comment: Try without `OH.OrderStatus` column.

Comment: From a quick glance the first query (pre-UNION) returns 12 columns, the second only returns 11 so SQL can't UNION those two result sets together.

Comment: My mistake I see what you are saying. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide have you seen the occurrence in which static text 'COSIGN AS Expr1' causes a "error converting data type varchar to numeric" before? I commented out every column except for the date field (OH.OrderDate)  and (CS.PriceTolerance). The OrderDate field is a decimal type.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide My apology for the question I understand the concept of using the static text. Its a place holder for any values that return from CS.PriceTolerance that may be empty and it takes its place. And since CS.PriceTolerance is a decimal type the value of 'COSIGN' will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [books online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql):

> Combines the results of two or more queries into a single result set
>   that includes all the rows that belong to all queries in the union.
>   The UNION operation is different from using joins that combine columns
>   from two tables.

You have 12 columns in your first select statement whereas others have 11 columns.  Comment out(or remove) `OH.OrderStatus` from the first select statement.